# Rotate an object arranged around a sphere to look at origin, then rotate it again

Tags: three.js

I know how to rotate an object arranged around a sphere so that it looks at the origin but how do I then rotate it again along the axis that runs from the center of the object to the origin of the sphere?

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/s3L6tqj0/

Everything I've tried hasn't worked, including code I had from before to do the same thing as `lookAt` but where I also add in my additional rotation.

I imagine it's something very simple I've missed - any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

You can use makeRotationAxis() to rotate along the axis from the origin of the sphere to the mesh. Assuming the sphere's origin is (0,0,0) you can do this:

```
var axis = new THREE.Vector3( mesh.position.x, mesh.position.y, mesh.position.z );
var angle = someAmountYoudLike * Math.PI / 256;
var matrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
matrix.makeRotationAxis( axis.normalize(), angle ); 
mesh.rotation.setFromRotationMatrix( matrix );
```

Comment: Thanks Bob - I tried that earlier so I hoped your solution had a line I missed but it still appears to be incorrect - http://jsfiddle.net/s3L6tqj0/1/ - did I miss something?I suspect my original description of the problem is wrong - imagine a large float on the ocean - I want to keep it flat on the surface but rotate about an axis from the center of the float to the center of the earth.

Answer (score 0):

As I imagined, the answer turned out to be really simple.

calling `rotateZ(angle)` on my object did the trick.

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/2hkg76se/